# Check jQuery Selectors in the Keys of Object to have a Non-Blank Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I to ensure that all the elements that are matched by the selectors in the keys of an object have a non-blank value? Mainly just trying to avoid too many arguments inside an if statement.

I've tried:

```
var credit_map = {
    "#first": "First Name",
    "#middle": "Middle Name",
    "#last": "Last Name",
    "#email": "Email Address",
    "#postalcode": "Zip/Postal Code",
    "#card_name": "Name on Card",
    "#card_number": "Card Number",
    "#card_month": "Card Experation Month",
    "#card_year": "Card Experation Year",
    "#card_verification": "Card Verification Code"
}

for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(credit_map)) {
    if ($(key).val() != null || undefined) {

    }
}
```

Comment: jQuery's `val` will never return `null`. It will only return `undefined` if you call it on an empty set (e.g., the selector you used to create the set didn't match any elements). Otherwise, it always returns a string.

Comment: How could I improve my question? I'm just trying to shorten the statement and make the code smell go away.

Comment: `variable != null` will be falsy if `variable` is null or undefined, so there's no need for `|| undefined`. There are plenty of questions about checking string variables for empty string, null, and undefined...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking how to ensure that all of the elements that are matched by the selectors in the keys of your object have a non-blank value. If so, you can use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
if (Object.keys(credit_map).every(sel => $(sel).val())) {
    // Yes, they all have non-blank values
} else {
    // No, at least one of them has a blank value (or didn't exist at all)
}
```

That works because both `""` and `undefined` are falsy values, and all non-blank strings are truthy. `every` converts the return value to boolean and uses it as a flag.

Comment: I still don't understand why we *need/have to* do this. Why do we need an object here? Also, I haven't heared that we can use this way to validate model. It's really hard to maintain. Imagine that what's happen if we add `<select>` or `<input type="file">` element to that form?

Comment: @Tân Do you have another suggestion? Just really trying to avoid doing != a bunch of times in an if statement. Also, because it sometimes returns undefined if you just check for a blank string.